# Program loses focus from touchscreen

Tags: focus

I have a program that loses focus and stops the enable capture mode because of a command such as clicking somewhere else or opening a new window. Is their a way to make these tasks undetectable to the program?I don't have the source code for this program either. Could their possibly be a program/autohotkey that would keep this focus and capture mode running? I had to turn my phone into a second monitor and leave the program there in order to use my pc normally without it losing focus.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a Windows System,

1 - And if you do a touch click on your Touchscreen, outsite the window from your program, it will automatic lose the focus from that window. (you can not eliminate to do that)

2 - or if the Program self opened a New Window it will automatic change the focus to that New Window. (you can not eliminate to do that)

The only thing that you can do is to Focus it back to that Program.

You can use this code.

Note: this is only a simple example how to use the commands [**IfWinActive**] and [**WinActivate**]

```
#SingleInstance Force
#WinActivateForce
; [^ = Ctrl] [+ = Shift] [! = Alt] [# = Win]

loop
{
;if Window with Class Tittle Name [Untitled - Notepad] is focused then focus back to Calculator program.
IfWinActive, Untitled - Notepad 
{
WinActivate, Calculator ;with this command, you can focus any Application.
}
}

;Click f1 key to recieved the Class Title Name
f1::
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
MsgBox, The active window is "%Title%"
return

esc::exitapp
```

if [Untitled - Notepad] Window is active (focused) it will automatic active back to program [Calculator]

Tip: to find the Class Title Name. you can also use the Autohotkey Applications.

1 - Windows Spy (Autohotkey build in)

[image: Window spy popupmenu][image: window spy]

or

2 - [WinSpy++](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28220)

[image: window spy pro]

Comment: The program that I am using only allows me to only do touchscreen input commands while running. It uses all the Keyboard and Mouse Devices when running because it is a game controller program that lets me use the mouse and keyboard on a game console.. So I cannot open anything without touching the screen when I enable capture mode. I want to be able to touch the screen without it disabling the capture mode so I can open this program Recentral. Which displays the game for me. [link](https://gyazo.com/32386890174464f55b9bb64a4cfc3604) [link](https://gyazo.com/b7c55e04fee51058f7781c057d0b38a7)

Comment: Here is also the image of the program I am trying to open that keeps making it lose focus [link](https://gyazo.com/21511e4dff65737882dd68b8c0c7d628)